# Bidirectional relationship OneToMany in Java Entity

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, foreign-keys, dbeaver

I am working with Jakarta (JPA) and postgres. I use DBeaver as a database manager. I have two entities defined, *teacher* and *subject*.

The relationship between them is, a teacher can teach several subjects, but a subject can only be taught by one teacher, this is a 1:N relationship in the sense of teacher and subject. I have modeled this with Jakarta, as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor 
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Subject.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Subject> subject;
    }
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subject")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor 
public class Subject {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private String id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_teacher_subject"))
    @JsonBackReference
    private Teacher teacher;
}
```

However, the data model (e-r model) that Dbeaver defines when starting the microservice only generates the relationship in the subject table, that is, I need my teacher table to contain a subject attribute and also for the subject table to contain an attribute teacher.

the relationship tags oneToMany and manyToOne are correctly defined.

After searching for information, I added the `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` tags in each of the entities to indicate which entity is the parent (*Teacher*) and child (*Subject*)

Why is the 'subject' attribute not generated correctly in Teacher?

Comment: That is correct for one to many, only a foreign key is generated. Why do you need a subject attribute in teacher?

Comment: Define 'correct' more clearly. What exactly do you expect from the table structure and maybe then you can look at the java entity model.

Comment: *The data model (e-r model) that Dbeaver defines ... only generates the relationship in the subject table*. That is **exactly** how is should be defined in a RDBMS. It says "for a given subject I get 1 teacher and for a given teacher I get many subjects". You do not want the subject in the teacher entity. Putting it there would require an array of subjects, thus making it a M:M relationship and at the same you violate 1NF.